# PhoneGap Webview WebSQL vs Chrome WebSQL device compatibility

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, webview

I have - 
tx.executeSql('insert into tbl (col1, col2) values (val01, val02), (val11, val12)...

This works well with - 
Android/Windows Chrome
Android Emulator running 4.1.x 
Android Tabs running 4.3.x +

However on some tabs, the app running on webview does not execute multiple insert statements. I searched on StackOverflow and other sources, and they say WebSQL supports Sqlite 3.6.19... and further research revealed bulk insert works on 3.7.11 and upwards... but if this is the case, then why does it work on some tabs running the same app on the same OS versions? All of them have either Android OS 4.3.x or 4.4.x and upwards.

If I run it on Android Chrome, it works fine... but if its run through Phonegap compiled app... it doesn't.

My config.xml has -

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="12" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="17" />
```

Phonegap Build log says -

```
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.1.1
[gettarget] API level:        22
```

.... why??

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations happen to use a more recent SQLite version than guaranteed. But as you have seen, you cannot rely on it.

Comment: BTW is chrome's sqlite the same one we use in native android apps? Or is it a bundled version?

Comment: Chrome typcially has its own copy.

Comment: I find Chrome's WebSQL/SQLite version to be more standard on all devices and platforms, but the one on WebView varies. 
As an alternate, I went with cordova's sqlite plugin
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-sqlite" source="npm" />
Cons - I cannot test it on my desktop using chrome now.. I have to use slow emulator always :(